# Google Apps Script DockPanel

Tags: google-apps-script

Could someone provide example of using DockPanel widget in GAS? More specifically, what does parameter direction in the method add(widget, direction) stands for, i.e how can be defined?

Answer (score 0):

The Apps Script UI widgets are based on the corresponding Google Web Toolkit (GWT) widgets. The [GWT DockPanel documentation](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockPanel.html) should provide you with more information.

Comment: I am aware of that, but when using direction constants from GWT (CENTER, WEST, EAST, NORTH, SOUTH) I get the error. `rootPanel
    .add(leftPanel,WEST)
    .add(centerPanel,CENTER)
    .add(rightPanel,EAST)
    .add(bottomPanel,SOUTH)
    .add(topPanel,"NORTH");`

Comment: I am aware of that, but when I try to use direction constants from GWT as in the following example: ` dockPanel.add(myLeftPanel,WEST).add(myRightPanel,EAST).add(myCenterPanel,CENTER).add(myTopPanel,NORTH).add(myBottomPanel,SOUTH)` i got an  error: ReferenceError: "WEST" is not defined. What's wrong with it?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't understand the question. It looks like the direction enum values weren't exposed, so it's currently not possible to set those directions. Please open an issue here: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list